# For someone to + verb

Tags: verbs, to-infinitive

> 8 minutes for this guy to fall down to earth yet it takes one hour for my Uber eats to be delivered

I saw this comment on a video on YouTube and I'd like to know if when I use 'for someone to + verb', whether I'd have to use 'to + verb' after the subject or not?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: The comment you saw presupposes: It takes 8 minutes etc. Comments are not always written with a subject, verb and predicate....to + verb shows a purpose.